# JSP changes are not reloading in Tomcat without restart

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, dcevm

I have a Dynamic Web Java-Spring Project setup in Eclipse running with DCEVM ([a Java virtual machine that allows code to be hotswapped into a web environment](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/)). I set this up with Eclipse. It works(!) as making changes to Java files automatically appear on browser refresh.

My question: how do I get the same behavior with my JSP files? When I edit these files in Eclipse they do not update in Tomcat. I currently run an ant task to copy them into my Tomcat directory, but was wondering if there was an alternative.

Comment: are you running tomcat in debug mode??? because DCEVM will only pickup changes when server is running in debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsp files are automatically recompiled after modification. This is standard behavior. But they must be in deploy directory. So if you modify source jsp then it is necessary to copy them to tomcat.

Comment: Is there a way to configure a Dynamic Web Project so that updated JSPs sync with the JSP files in the Tomcat webapp?

Comment: It is not task for VM. You need to deploy source files. I do not understand your problem. Ant is fine, eclipse shall do it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Setting "antiResourceLocking" to "true" in the context file may prevent JSP to be reloaded by the Tomcat ([Bugzilla 37668](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37668)).

Try to remove this parameter.

btw: in you ide there should be also an option to "deploy on save" you jsp.

Comment: That was exactly the cause of my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory of tomcat -> conf -> web.xml.  There is a setting called "Development".  Change this from false to true and it will automatically reload every time you load the page.